# How to manage MSP using hyperledger fabric CA?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

1) Can we use hyperledger fabric-ca to manage MSP.?

2) If yes how to configure it.?

3) Can we generate MSP using hyperledger fabric-ca?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found solution we can avoid using binaries and generate MSP using fabric-ca.

check fabric-samples in that fabric-ca directory, first run.

```
$: ./makeDocker.sh (this will generate docker-compose.yaml file)
```

then run

```
$: ./start.sh
```

this will spin up docker containers and install sample chaincode and enroll peer and orderer users on fabric-ca